# How Can I handle any url beginning with some url in Go?

Tags: go

Hi I am using gorilla/mux in go, and I want to handle any url that begins with : "/a/b/c"

I tried:

```
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
router.HandleFunc(`/a/b/{_dummy:c(\/)?.*}`, Func1)
```

that is the url can be /a/b/c/d or /a/b/c/d/e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the documentation for gorilla/mux: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Route.PathPrefix

```
func (r *Router) PathPrefix(tpl string) *Route
```

> PathPrefix registers a new route with a matcher for the URL path
>   prefix. See Route.PathPrefix().

```
func (r *Route) PathPrefix(tpl string) *Route
```

> PathPrefix adds a matcher for the URL path prefix. This matches if the
>   given template is a prefix of the full URL path. See Route.Path() for
>   details on the tpl argument.
>
> Note that it does not treat slashes specially ("/foobar/" will be
>   matched by the prefix "/foo") so you may want to use a trailing slash
>   here.
>
> Also note that the setting of Router.StrictSlash() has no effect on
>   routes with a PathPrefix matcher.

---

> Note that the path provided to PathPrefix() represents a "wildcard":
>   calling PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(...) means that the handler
>   will be passed any request that matches "/static/*".

So what you're looking for is:

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.PathPrefix("/a/b/c/").HandleFunc(proxy.GrafanaHandler) // matches /a/b/c/*
```